# Spring Boot Junit Test - Cannot get some values from application-test.yml (returns null)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a problem to write the JUnit Test with the usage of resttemplate.

When I run the testCalculateRate, I got this error message shown below

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.getBody()" because "responseEntity" is null
```

Next, I debug the code

`getExchangeUrl` returns this null2023-05-22?symbols=USD%2CGBP&base=EUR as `EXCHANGE_API_BASE_URL` returns null. `EXCHANGE_API_API_KEY` also returns null.

Here is the Constants shown below

```java
@Component
public class Constants {

    public static String EXCHANGE_API_BASE_URL;
    public static String EXCHANGE_API_API_KEY;

    public static String EXCHANGE_CACHE_NAME;
    public static Integer EXCHANGE_API_CALL_LIMIT;

    @Value("${exchange-api.api-url}")
    public void setExchangeApiBaseUrl(String apiUrl) {
        EXCHANGE_API_BASE_URL = apiUrl;
    }

    @Value("${exchange-api.api-key}")
    public void setExchangeApiKey(String apiKey) {
        EXCHANGE_API_API_KEY = apiKey;
    }

    @Value("${exchange-api.cache-name}")
    public void setExchangeCacheName(String cacheName) {
        EXCHANGE_CACHE_NAME = cacheName;
    }

    @Value("${exchange-api.api-call-limit}")
    public void setExchangeApiCallLimit(Integer apiCallLimit) {
        EXCHANGE_API_CALL_LIMIT = apiCallLimit;
    }

}
```

Here is the relevant part of application-test.yml

```yaml
exchange-api:
  api-url: https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/
  api-key: ${EXCHANGE_API_API_KEY:default-key}
  api-call-limit: 60
  cache-name: exchanges
  cache-ttl: 10000
```

Here RateServiceTest shown below

```java
    import static com.exchangeapi.currencyexchange.constants.Constants.EXCHANGE_API_API_KEY;
    import static com.exchangeapi.currencyexchange.constants.Constants.EXCHANGE_API_BASE_URL;
    
    class RateServiceTest extends BaseServiceTest {
    
        @Mock
        private RateRepository rateRepository;
    
        @Mock
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
        @InjectMocks
        private RateService rateService;
    
        @Test
        void testCalculateRate() {
    
            // Initialize mocks
            MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    
            // Mocked data
            EnumCurrency base = EnumCurrency.EUR;
            List<EnumCurrency> targets = Arrays.asList(EnumCurrency.USD, EnumCurrency.GBP);
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2023, 5, 22);
    
            // Mocked rate entity
            RateEntity mockedRateEntity = new RateEntity();
            mockedRateEntity.setBase(base);
            mockedRateEntity.setDate(date);
            Map<EnumCurrency, Double> rates = new HashMap<>();
            rates.put(EnumCurrency.USD, 1.2);
            rates.put(EnumCurrency.GBP, 0.9);
            mockedRateEntity.setRates(rates);
    
            // Mock repository behavior
            when(rateRepository.findOneByDate(date)).thenReturn(Optional.of(mockedRateEntity));
    
            // Mock API response
            RateResponse mockedRateResponse = RateResponse.builder()
                    .base(base)
                    .rates(rates)
                    .date(date)
                    .build();
    
            // Create a HttpHeaders object and set the "apikey" header
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("apikey", EXCHANGE_API_API_KEY);
    
            // Create a mock response entity with the expected headers and body
            ResponseEntity<RateResponse> mockedResponseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .body(mockedRateResponse);
    
            // Mock RestTemplate behavior
            when(restTemplate.exchange(
                    anyString(),
                    eq(HttpMethod.GET),
                    any(HttpEntity.class),
                    eq(RateResponse.class)
            )).thenReturn(mockedResponseEntity);
    
            // Call the method
            RateDto result = rateService.calculateRate(base, targets, date);
    
            // Verify repository method was called
            verify(rateRepository, times(1)).findOneByDate(date);
    
            // Verify API call was made
            String expectedUrl = getExchangeUrl(date, base, targets);
            HttpHeaders expectedHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            expectedHeaders.add("apikey", EXCHANGE_API_API_KEY);
            HttpEntity<String> expectedHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(expectedHeaders);
            verify(restTemplate, times(1)).exchange(
                    eq(expectedUrl),
                    eq(HttpMethod.GET),
                    eq(expectedHttpEntity),
                    eq(RateResponse.class)
            );
    
            // Verify the result
            assertThat(result.getBase()).isEqualTo(base);
            assertThat(result.getDate()).isEqualTo(date);
            assertThat(result.getRates()).hasSize(2);
            assertThat(result.getRates()).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(
                    new RateInfoDto(EnumCurrency.USD, 1.2),
                    new RateInfoDto(EnumCurrency.GBP, 0.9)
            );
        }
    
        private String getExchangeUrl(LocalDate rateDate, EnumCurrency base, List<EnumCurrency> targets) {
    
            String symbols = String.join("%2C", targets.stream().map(EnumCurrency::name).toArray(String[]::new));
            return EXCHANGE_API_BASE_URL + rateDate + "?symbols=" + symbols + "&base=" + base;
        }
    }
```

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/currencyexchange)

Comment: Your `BaseServiceTest` is missing the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. Without it, spring features do not work.

Comment: @YevheniiSemenov I revised it but nothing changed. I still got the error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.getBody()" because "responseEntity" is null`

Comment: You should also make your constants not static, define getters for them and inject `Constants` bean to your tests through `@Autowire` instead of using it directly.

Comment: @YevheniiSemenov I got the right url and api key from there as last. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added @SpingBootTest annotation in BaseServiceTest and clicked "Invalid Cache" , the issue was disappeared.

Here is BaseServiceTest shown below

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")
public abstract class BaseServiceTest {

}
```

Comment: Accessing the `application-test.yml` requires loaded application context and unit test runs in isolated environment without the application context. This is why we use @SpringBootTest annotation to load up application context and access the application properties file.